# What is the difference between torch.tensor and torch.Tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

What is the difference between [`torch.tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tensor.html#torch.tensor) and [`torch.Tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor)? What was the reasoning for providing these two very similar and confusing alternatives?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In PyTorch `torch.Tensor` is the main tensor class. So all tensors are just instances of `torch.Tensor`.

When you call `torch.Tensor()` you will get an empty tensor without any `data`.

In contrast `torch.tensor` is a function which returns a tensor. In the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.tensor) it says:

> ```
> torch.tensor(data, dtype=None, device=None, requires_grad=False) → Tensor
> ```
>
> Constructs a tensor with `data`.

---

This also explains why it is no problem creating an empty tensor instance of `torch.Tensor` without `data` by calling:

```
tensor_without_data = torch.Tensor()
```

But on the other side:

```
tensor_without_data = torch.tensor()
```

Will lead to an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-ebc3ceaa76d2> in <module>()
----> 1 torch.tensor()

TypeError: tensor() missing 1 required positional arguments: "data"
```

---

But in general there is no reason to choose `torch.Tensor` over `torch.tensor`. Also `torch.Tensor` lacks a docstring.

Similar behaviour for creating a tensor without `data` like with: `torch.Tensor()` can be achieved using:

```
torch.tensor(())
```

Output:

```
tensor([])
```

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the above answers, I noticed:

- `torch.Tensor()` creates a tensor with the default data type, as defined by `torch.get_default_dtype()`.
- `torch.tensor()` will infer data type from the data.

For example:

```
>>> torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3]).dtype
torch.float32

>>> torch.tensor([1, 2, 3]).dtype
torch.int64
```

Answer (score 9):

According to discussion on [pytorch discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-tensor-and-tensor-is-tensor-going-to-be-deprecated-in-the-future/17134/5)
 `torch.Tensor` constructor is overloaded to do the same thing as both `torch.tensor` and `torch.empty`. It is  thought this overload would make code confusing, so  split `torch.Tensor` into `torch.tensor` and `torch.empty`.

So yes, to some extent, `torch.tensor` works similarly to torch.Tensor (when you pass in data).  no, neither should be more efficient than the other. It's just that the `torch.empty` and `torch.tensor` have a nicer API than  `torch.Tensor` constructor.

Answer (score 5):

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/difference-between-torch-tensor-and-torch-tensor/30786/2

> torch.tensor infers the dtype automatically, while torch.Tensor
> returns a torch.FloatTensor. I would recommend to stick to
> torch.tensor, which also has arguments like dtype, if you would like
> to change the type.

Answer (score 2):

[`torch.Tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=torch%20tensor#torch.Tensor) is a favorite method used when creating parameters (for instance in [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/linear.html#Linear), [`nn._ConvNd`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/conv.html)).

Why? Because it is very fast. It is even a bit faster than [`torch.empty()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.empty.html).

```
import torch
torch.set_default_dtype(torch.float32) # default

%timeit torch.empty(1000,1000)
%timeit torch.Tensor(1000,1000)
%timeit torch.ones(1000,1000)
%timeit torch.tensor([[1]*1000]*1000)
```

Out:

```
68.4 µs ± 789 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
67.9 µs ± 349 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
1.26 ms ± 8.61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
36.1 ms ± 610 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

`torch.Tensor()` and `and torch.empty()` are very similar and return a tensor filled with uninitialized data.

Why do we not initialize parameters in `__init__` while technically this is possible?

Here is the `torch.Tensor` in practice inside `nn.Linear` to create the `weight` parameter:

```
self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features, in_features))
```

We do not initialize it per design. There is another `reset_parameters()` method and because while training it may need to "reset" the parameters again, we call `reset_paremeters()` at the end of the `__init__()` method.

Maybe in the future `torch.empty()` will replace `torch.Tensor()` because these are the same in effect.

Also there is one nice option with `reset_parameters()`, you may create your own version and alter the original initialization procedure if needed.

Comment: There seem to be some flaws in these performance comparisons. The first two measurements are not at least one sigma apart, and the last measurement is flawed because it also measures the `[[1]*1000]*1000` call which is probably slow and dominates the runtime.

Comment: @Turakar No, it does not dominate the runtime.
`py -m timeit "a = [[1]*1000]*1000" 
50000 loops, best of 5: 5.11 usec per loop`

And also including that as part  of the setup,
`py -m timeit -s "import torch; a = [[1]*1000]*1000" "torch.tensor(a)" 
10 loops, best of 5: 31.7 msec per loop`

Comment: Interesting, seems like I was wrong.