# Pytorch - RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'target' in call to _thnn_nll_loss_forward

Tags: python, pytorch, loss, cross-entropy

I was trying & experimenting something with PyTorch, where I created my own inputs & targets. I fed these inputs to the model (which is a basic ANN with 2 hidden layers, nothing wrong with that). But for some reason I am not being able to calculate the CrossEntropyLoss(). I am not being able to figure out why. I know some of the other questions on StakcOverflow have the same title of mine or have a similar problem. I have gone through that but nothing worked out for me. Alot of people had an issue with the dataset, which does not seem to be the problem with me.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(2, 10)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.layer1(x))
        x = self.layer2(x)
        return x
    
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = Net().to(device=device)
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
learning_rate = 1e-3
epochs = 20
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
inputs = torch.Tensor([
    [0,0],
    [0,1],
    [1,0],
    [1,1]
], ).to(device=device)

targets = torch.Tensor([
    0,
    1,
    1,
    0
]).to(device=device)

model.train()
for epoch in range(epochs):

    pred_output = model(inputs)
    print(pred_output.dtype)
    print(targets.dtype)
    loss = loss_fn(pred_output, targets)
    
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print()
    break
```

The error that I see is,

```
torch.float32
torch.float32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 57, in <module>
    loss = loss_fn(pred_output, targets)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 1047, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2693, in cross_entropy
    return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2388, in nll_loss
    ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'target' in call to _thnn_nll_loss_forward
```

Answer (score 3):

I could replicate you error using this code.

```
import torch.nn as nn
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
target = torch.tensor([1., 2., 3.])
loss(input, target)
```

Error:

> RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float

changed the datatype of target to `target = torch.tensor([1., 2., 3.], dtype=torch.long)` and everything worked fine. I believe the target variable does require long datatype because changing the input to float will also work.

```
#this will also work
input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float)
target = torch.tensor([1., 2., 3.], dtype=torch.long)
loss(input, target)
```

Note the documentation also has this `torch.long` dtype in example code. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html

#Edit 1
The reason it's not working is because of the way you defined input/target tensors in your code. Use `torch.tensor` with a small 't' instead of `torch.Tensor`. For a detailed discussion see [What is the difference between torch.tensor and torch.Tensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911749/what-is-the-difference-between-torch-tensor-and-torch-tensor).

```
#this will work. Also notice the decimal. otherwise it will be interpreted differently by pytorch
inputs = torch.tensor([[0.,0.],[0.,1.],[1.,0.],[1.,1.]]).to(device=device)
targets = torch.tensor([0.,1.,1.,0.], dtype=torch.long).to(device=device)
```

Comment: I tried this, 
`py
targets = torch.Tensor([
    0,
    1,
    1,
    0
], dtype=torch.long).to(device=device)
`

Comment: But still faced another issue,
`cmd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 44, in <module>
    targets = torch.Tensor([
TypeError: new() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (list, dtype=torch.dtype), but expected one of:
 * (*, torch.device device)
      didn't match because some of the keywords were incorrect: dtype
 * (torch.Storage storage)
 * (Tensor other)
 * (tuple of ints size, *, torch.device device)
 * (object data, *, torch.device device)
`

Comment: I have no issue with adding `to(device=device)`. what are you using - 'cpu' or 'cuda' ?

Comment: cuda,
I am currently using a GPU

Comment: hmm. I was using a cpu and it worked. This also woked with a gpu if I don't assign the target to the device.

Comment: I'll update the whole program in the ques, can you please try to run it

Comment: I have edited the answer to solve the new error.