# Turning variable into a torch Tensor. Afterwards tensor is empty / has no element

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, tensor, dataloader

The following is my Code. The "sequences" are my training data in the form [139 rows x 4 columns], 0) where the 139x4 are my signals and the 0 is my encoded label.

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    sequence, label = self.sequences[idx]
  
    #converting sequence and label to tensors 
    sequence = torch.Tensor(sequence.to_numpy())
      
    print("label before tensor", label)
    label = torch.Tensor(label).long()
    print("numel() labels   :", label.numel())
    print("label shape    :", shape(label))
    return (sequence, label)
```

The Code output is:

```
      >>label before tensor 0  (This is my encoded label)
      >>numel() labels   : 0
      >>label shape    : torch.Size([0])
```

Why is my label tensor empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `torch.Tensor` expects either an array (in which case this array becomes the underlying values) or several `int`s which will be the size of the tensor. Hence `torch.Tensor(0)` instantiates a tensor of size 0.

Either you use `torch.Tensor([0])` or `torch.tensor(0)`. Why these two objects behave in a different manner I don't know, but I'd recommend using the `tensor` (not capitalized) since it's better documented (the `Tensor` one seems to be part of the C port)

edit : found [this useful thread about their difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911749/what-is-the-difference-between-torch-tensor-and-torch-tensor)