# Create a PyTorch tensor of sequences which excludes specified value

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a 1d PyTorch tensor containing integers between `0` and `n-1`. Now I need to create a 2d PyTorch tensor with `n-1` columns, where each row is a sequence from `0` to `n-1` excluding the value in the first tensor. How can I achieve this efficiently?

Ex:

```
n = 3
a = torch.Tensor([0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0])
# desired output
b = [
    [1, 2],
    [0, 2],
    [0, 1],
    [0, 2],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 2]
  ]
```

Typically, the `a.numel()` >> `n`.

**Detailed Explanation**:
The first element of `a` is `0`, hence it has to map to the sequence `[0, 1, 2]` excluding `0`, which is `[1, 2]`.
Similarly, the second element of `a` is `1`, hence it has to map to `[0, 2]` and so on.

PS: I actually have an additional batch dimension, which I've excluded here for simplicity. Hence, I need the solution to be easily extendable to one additional dimension.

Comment: I don't follow. Could you clarify how the input maps to the output?

Comment: Added. Is that helpful?

Comment: I have a solution, adding as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can construct a tensor with the desired sequences and index with tensor *a*.

```py
import torch

n = 3
a = torch.Tensor([0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0]) # using torch.tensor is recommended

def exclude_gather(a, n):
    sequences = torch.nonzero(torch.arange(n) != torch.arange(n)[:,None], as_tuple=True)[1].reshape(-1, n-1)
    return sequences[a.long()]

exclude_gather(a, n)
```

Output

```
tensor([[1, 2],
        [0, 2],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2],
        [0, 1],
        [1, 2]])
```

We can add a batch dimension with [`functorch.vmap`](https://pytorch.org/functorch/stable/generated/functorch.vmap.html#functorch-vmap)

```
from functorch import vmap

n = 4
b = torch.Tensor([[0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0],[0, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1]])

vmap(exclude_gather, in_dims=(0, None))(b, n)
```

Output

```
tensor([[[1, 2, 3],
         [0, 2, 3],
         [0, 1, 3],
         [0, 2, 3],
         [0, 1, 2],
         [1, 2, 3]],

        [[1, 2, 3],
         [0, 1, 2],
         [0, 2, 3],
         [1, 2, 3],
         [0, 1, 3],
         [0, 2, 3]]])
```

Comment: +1 for `functorch.vmap`. Also, why is `torch.tensor` recommended over `torch.Tensor`? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51911888/3337089) answer suggests there is no performance improvement.

Comment: It's only a [recommendation](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-tensor-and-tensor-is-tensor-going-to-be-deprecated-in-the-future/17134/6) to avoid unexpected results. `torch.Tensor` can cause hard-to-find bugs assuming it is the same as `torch.tensor`. Sry, same link as you've already provided.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is initialize a multi-dimension array with all possible indices using `torch.arange()`. After that, purge indices that you don't want from each tensor using a boolean mask.

```
import torch

a = torch.Tensor([0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0])
n = 3
b = [torch.arange(n) for i in range(len(a))]
c = [b[i]!=a[i] for i in range(len(b))]
# use the boolean array as a mask to apply on b
d = [[b[i][c[i]] for i in range(len(b))]]

print(d) # this can be converted to a list of numbers or torch tensor
```

This prints the output - `[[tensor([1, 2]), tensor([0, 2]), tensor([0, 1]), tensor([0, 2]), tensor([0, 1]), tensor([1, 2])]]` which you can convert to int/numpy/torch array/tensor easily.

This can be extended to multiple dimensions as well.

Comment: This uses too many for loops :( In my case, the size of `a` is large and hence this may be sub-optimal.

Answer (score 0):

The following does the trick

```
b = []
for i in range(n-1):
    b.append(i * torch.ones_like(a) + (a <= i))
b = torch.stack(b, dim=1)
```

Since `n << size(a)`, the for loop should not be very costly.